# Как добавть сертефикат CA на TV Эмулятор?

Tags: тестирование, testng

Суть такова: Есть Tv эмулятор. Есть приложение .apk. Запросы передаются по https.
Необходимо с помощью Charles/Fiddler проснифить трафик этого приложения. Для просмотра https трафика Charles/Fiddler используют сертификаты CA. Вопрос, можно ли их установить на Tv? Google play/ браузера на TV нету.
Соурс кода тоже нету. Есть только само приложение.

Есть возможность протестировать на живом TV. Но чаще тестирую на эмуляторе

Comment: "передаются по https." и я хочу их отследить. Куда, по чем и сколько, а самое главное что мы получим в ответ. Я вас правельно понял?

Comment: Существует стенд на котором https трафик. Необходимо отследить запросы реализованные через Rest API. Просмотреть Как ответ и тело самого запроса. На телефоне спокойно можно это сделать через установек сертефиката, а на TV без понятия

Comment: На компе я бы сделал так, установил эмулятор андроид на комп, установил приложение .apk на эмулятор. Смотрим трафик через Charles/Fiddler

Comment: Самая главная проблема что тестить нужно именно на TV, а как на телефон его туда не поставить

Comment: Как вариант пускать трафик от/на телевизор через комп.